# Store Spring security ACL to a nosql structure

Tags: spring, spring-security, cassandra, acl

I work on a project which uses Spring Security. I would like to use the ACL mechanism to manage security on domain object.

The problem is that my project uses Cassandra and elastic search, and so no sql database.

Is there a way to store spring security ACL into a nosql structure (cassandra) or indexer (elastic search) to avoid creating a relational database specifically for ACL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an implementation of nosql data structures for spring security domain ACL's. It should be simple if you want to implement one on your own. Start looking at `MutableAclService` and `LookupStrategy` interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently looking for something that might already exist and came across this project on GitHub [spring-acl-cassandra](https://github.com/RigasGrigoropoulos/spring-security-acl-cassandra).  (I've not tried this project yet.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a project now, specifically to connect Spring ACL to Cassandra:

https://github.com/RigasGrigoropoulos/spring-security-acl-cassandra